# ATMEGA32 LED BLINKER Assembly code problem

Tags: led, avr, assembly

I tried the following code for a simple led blinking problem on ATMega32.

```
INCLUDE "M32DEF.INC"

SBI DDRC,5
LDI R16,0xFF
OUT PORTC,R16

AGAIN:LDI R19,255
LOOP1:LDI R18,255
LOOP2:LDI R20,5
LOOP3:NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
DEC R20
BRNE LOOP3
DEC R18
BRNE LOOP2

DEC R19
BRNE LOOP1

COM R16
OUT PORTC,R16

RJMP AGAIN
```

According to the code the output is set at PortC-5. The datasheet says it works at pin 27. The simulation in Proteus works fine. However after burning the code on the chip, the actual output comes at pin 28.

The chip I am using is an Atmel ATMEGA32A PU 1527. Some of the other people who tried this had the same at pin number 29 too. Why is it happening? I am new to this field, so please help me out here.

Comment: Do you see the "output" on pin 27 and pin 28/29 too, or just pin 28/29? See answer below.

Comment: I checked it on all the pins,for some reason only pin 28 gave me the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> COM R16
> ```

This complements the ***entire register***. Outputting this then flips *all 8 bits in PORTC*. Consider using `EOR` to flip only the single bit in the register instead.

Comment: That shouldn't lead to the observed behavior because only PC5 is configured as output.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn: On pins that are configured as an input, toggling their `PORTx` bit enables or disables the internal pullup.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. So the poster will see the voltage across the pullup resistor on the pins.

Comment: But the problem I am facing is that only pin 28 uniquely gives me the output.The LED doesn't even give light at the others.While simulating in Proteus the simulation yields a blinking led only if the wire was connected to pin 27.And I am using the internal clock of the chip.

Comment: Did you disable JTAG?

Comment: I don't know the code for doing that in Assembly.Do you disable it while burning the code?

Comment: Have you looked at the two JTAG sections in the datasheet yet?

Comment: Yes,I looked them up.Thank you very much for the help.I apologize for the lack of structure in some of my statements .This is my first program on AVR for a lab course,so I had not learnt about JTAG yet.